How to remove '/page' text from page size dropdown in el-pagination
<el-pagination
  v-model:current-page="currentPage2"
  v-model:page-size="pageSize2"
  :page-sizes="[100, 200, 300, 400]"
  :small="small"
  :disabled="disabled"
  :background="background"
  layout="sizes, prev, pager, next"
  :total="1000"
  @size-change="handleSizeChange"
  @current-change="handleCurrentChange"
/>

By default the page size dropdown shows text like "10/pages", I need to show it simply "10", "20". How can I remove the "/pages" part?

If it's not supported by the API, you'll need to request the developers add support. This is the tradeoff of using opinionated component libraries. The original developer decides much of the look and feel for you. For alternative solution, you may need to develop your own custom pagination component.
